# How do I reduce memory allocation in my ODE in Julia?

Tags: performance, memory, indexing, struct, julia

I am using a struct in julia called "Droplet" which has fields for certain parameters of a particle such as x,y,z location, radius, and speed in the x,y,z directions. These are type specified as Float64 values:

```
module ParticlePoints

mutable struct Droplet
radius::Float64
osmolarity::Float64
x::Float64
y::Float64
z::Float64
xvelocity::Float64
yvelocity::Float64
zvelocity::Float64
xacceleration::Float64
yacceleration::Float64
zacceleration::Float64
searchradius::Float64
end # End the struct
```

I import the module into the ODE file and populate it each timestep. The droplet fields are given by indices from the vector u. Using view() doesn't work for the assignment because view gives me a sub-array. Is there any way to just get the float 64 value out of the view command, or a way to get the float 64 value out of the indices without consuming memory? Regardless, it is consuming a huge amount of memory for the following code, including large memory consumption for the line where I just specify droplet.searchradius as "10.":

```
for i in 1:dropletcount
    # display(typeof(droplets[i]))
    droplets[i].radius = getindex(u,i,1)::Float64
    droplets[i].osmolarity = getindex(u, i+dropletcount)::Float64
    droplets[i].x = getindex(u, Int(i+2*dropletcount))::Float64
    droplets[i].y = getindex(u, Int(i+3*dropletcount))::Float64
    droplets[i].z = getindex(u, Int(i+4*dropletcount))::Float64
    droplets[i].xvelocity =  getindex(u, Int(i+5*dropletcount))::Float64
    droplets[i].yvelocity =  getindex(u, Int(i+6*dropletcount))::Float64
    droplets[i].zvelocity =  getindex(u, Int(i+7*dropletcount))::Float64
    droplets[i].searchradius =  10.
    # display(typeof(droplets[i]))
end # End the for loop
```

The struct droplet is stored in a seperate module called particle points and is imported at the start of the module as such:

```
module MyDropletVectorJComponents
include("myparticlepoints.jl")
# include("myquadtreequery.jl")
using Interpolations
using LinearAlgebra
using RegionTrees
using StaticArrays: SVector
import RegionTrees: AbstractRefinery, needs_refinement, refine_data, adaptivesampling!
using .ParticlePoints
using DifferentialEquations

# The exports of this particular module 
# export mydropfun!, myOvitoPrint!
export dropvecj!
```

I do not know why assigning a float64 value to this struct field which is type specified as float64 is causing such large memory allocations. The "droplets" you see is a vector that is called outside the ODE function and then imported in using the parameters p:

```
      # Create the vector of droplets that will be fed into the main ODE 
  droplets::Vector{Droplet} = Droplet[] # Change this to a vector that needs to be imported in 
  for i in 1:outerdropletcount
      droplet::Droplet = Droplet(0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.)  #< ----- > THE FORMATTING FOR THE DROPLET
      push!(droplets, droplet)
  end # End the for loop
# typeof(droplets)
# display(droplets)
# Create the current residual that makes the osmolarity activate after the droplets settle
#   normvelocity = zeros(1,1)



p = [outerdropletcount, k, L, γ, D, boolean_osm, dradii, dosmolarities, dvelocities, ρ, accelerationvec, droplets, xyzaccel, flux] 
prob = ODEProblem(mydropfun!, ICvector, tspan, p)
sol = solve(prob, Tsit5(), reltol=1e-8, saveat = 0.1)
```

Additionally, it should be specified that the file containing the struct is in a separate file but  in the same folder/directory as the ODE. Also the ODE and the function that lays out some of the parameters like the aforementioned "droplets" vector are in the same file. Any help would be deeply appreciated, and I am happy to provide more information on request.

EDIT: Here is a full MWE of the code. I reduced as much as I could. This should run:

```
module MyOvitoPrint
export myovitoprint
function myovitoprint(sol, dropletcount)
    # This function will recast the solution of our ordinary differential equation into a printed file that can be visualized in ovito.
    V = convert(Array,sol) # Convert the ODE solution into an array that can be worked on 
    V = dropdims(V, dims = 2) # Dimension 2 is a singleton and should be eliminated
    totalsteps::Int64 = size(V,2)
    # Create the empty string vector that will be used to create the printout 
    myprintout = Array{String}(undef, (5+dropletcount)*totalsteps, 1)
    # Initialize the timestep 
    timestep::Float64 = 0.
    stepindex::Int64 = 1

    for i in 1:  5+dropletcount:  (5+dropletcount)*totalsteps
        myprintout[i] = "ITEM: TIMESTEP"
        myprintout[i+1] = "$timestep"
        myprintout[i+2] = "ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS"
        myprintout[i+3] = "$dropletcount"
        myprintout[i+4] = "ITEM: ATOMS x y z radius osmolarity"
       for j in 1:dropletcount
            # myprintout[i+4+j] = "$x $y $z $radius $osmolarity"
            x = V[2*dropletcount+j, stepindex]
            y = V[3*dropletcount+j, stepindex]
            z = V[4*dropletcount+j, stepindex]
            radius = V[j, stepindex]
            osmolarity = V[dropletcount + j, stepindex]
            myprintout[i+4+j] = "$x $y $z $radius $(osmolarity)"
       end # End sub-loop for droplets
       stepindex += 1 
       timestep += 0.1 
    end # End loop
    # Now print the .xyz file
    outfile = "E:/Research Scripts and Functions/OVITO_Files/visual_model.ovito"
    f = open(outfile, "w")
    for i in eachindex(myprintout)   
        println(f, myprintout[i])
    end
    close(f)
end # Function end 
end # End module MyOvitoPrint

module DropletFields 
export Droplet, TreeCellData
mutable struct Droplet
    radius::Float64
    osmolarity::Float64
    x::Float64
    y::Float64
    z::Float64
    xvelocity::Float64
    yvelocity::Float64
    zvelocity::Float64
    xacceleration::Float64
    yacceleration::Float64
    zacceleration::Float64
    searchradius::Float64
end # End the struct
mutable struct TreeCellData
    list::Vector{Droplet}
    endindex::Int64
end # End the struct
end # End module DropletFields

module NateDropOde
# Imports ----- 
using ..DropletFields
using RegionTrees
using StaticArrays: SVector
import RegionTrees: AbstractRefinery, needs_refinement, refine_data, adaptivesampling!
using DifferentialEquations
# Exports ----- 
export natedropode
function natedropode(du, u, p, t)
    # Put in the parameters that are needed, very important line of code: #=========================================================================
    dropletcount, k, L, γ, D, boolean_osm, dradii, dosmolarities, dvelocities, ρ, accelerationvec, droplets, xyzaccel, flux = p;
    maxradius = 0. 
    dropletcount = dropletcount 
    maxradius = maximum(view(u,1:dropletcount))
    normvelocity = 0.
    ℷ = abs.(view(u, 5*dropletcount+1:8*dropletcount))
    ℸ = view(u, 5*dropletcount+1:8*dropletcount)
    Ζ = view(u, 5*dropletcount+1:8*dropletcount)
    broadcast(abs, ℸ)
    ℶ = view(u, 5*dropletcount+1:8*dropletcount).^2
    ℵ= sum(ℶ)
    ℵ  = sqrt(ℵ)
    if (t > 0.1 && normvelocity/dropletcount <= 1e-4)  
        boolean_osm[1] = 1.0
    end # End conditional
    for i in 1:dropletcount
        # display(typeof(droplets[i]))
        droplets[i].radius = getindex(u,i,1)::Float64
        droplets[i].osmolarity = getindex(u, i+dropletcount)::Float64
        droplets[i].x = getindex(u, Int(i+2*dropletcount))::Float64
        droplets[i].y = getindex(u, Int(i+3*dropletcount))::Float64
        droplets[i].z = getindex(u, Int(i+4*dropletcount))::Float64
        droplets[i].xvelocity =  getindex(u, Int(i+5*dropletcount))::Float64
        droplets[i].yvelocity =  getindex(u, Int(i+6*dropletcount))::Float64
        droplets[i].zvelocity =  getindex(u, Int(i+7*dropletcount))::Float64
        droplets[i].searchradius =  10.
        # display(typeof(droplets[i]))
    end # End the for loop
    xvec = view(u, Int(2*dropletcount+1):Int(3*dropletcount))
    xorigin::Float64 = minimum(xvec) - 0.1
    yvec = view(u, Int(3*dropletcount+1):Int(4*dropletcount))
    yorigin::Float64 = minimum(yvec) - 0.1
    zvec = view(u, Int(4*dropletcount+1):Int(5*dropletcount))
    zorigin::Float64 = minimum(zvec) - 0.1
    xwidth::Float64 = (maximum(xvec) - xorigin) * 1.1
    ywidth::Float64 = (maximum(yvec) - yorigin) * 1.1
    zwidth::Float64 = (maximum(zvec) - zorigin) * 1.1
    r = MyRefinery(0.0)
    asaf = TreeCellData(droplets, dropletcount)
    root::Cell = Cell(SVector(xorigin, yorigin, zorigin), SVector(xwidth, ywidth, zwidth), asaf)
    myquadtree = adaptivesampling!(root, r)
    for i in 1:dropletcount
        fill!(xyzaccel, 0.)
        flux[1] = 0.
        jvec = 0.
        query(myquadtree, droplets[i], xyzaccel, flux, L, k, boolean_osm, D, jvec, accelerationvec)
        myvolume = 4/3 * pi * droplets[i].radius^3
        dvelocities[i] = (xyzaccel[1] - γ * droplets[i].xvelocity) / (ρ * myvolume) 
        dvelocities[i+dropletcount] = (xyzaccel[2] - γ * droplets[i].yvelocity) / (ρ * myvolume) 
        dvelocities[i+2*dropletcount] = (xyzaccel[3] - γ * droplets[i].zvelocity) / (ρ * myvolume) 
        mymoles = droplets[i].osmolarity * myvolume
        myvolume = myvolume + flux[1]  
        dradii[i] = (3/(4*pi) * myvolume)^(1/3) - droplets[i].radius
        dosmolarities[i] = mymoles/myvolume - droplets[i].osmolarity
    end # End the for loop
    du[1:dropletcount] = dradii
    du[dropletcount+1 : 2*dropletcount] = dosmolarities
    du[2*dropletcount+1 : 5*dropletcount] = view(u, 5*dropletcount+1:8*dropletcount)
    du[5*dropletcount+1 : 8*dropletcount] = dvelocities
end # End the main function

struct MyRefinery <: AbstractRefinery
    tolerance::Int64
end # End struct


function needs_refinement(r::MyRefinery, cell)
    myindex::Int64 = 0 
    for i in 1:cell.data.endindex
        # Adress an edge case where the point sits directly in top of the line of division
        edgecorrectionx = 0.
        edgecorrectiony = 0.
        edgecorrectionz = 0. 
        
        edgecasex1::Bool = cell.data.list[i].x == cell.boundary.origin[1] 
        edgecasex2::Bool = cell.data.list[i].x == cell.boundary.origin[1] + cell.boundary.widths[1] 
        edgecasey1::Bool = cell.data.list[i].y == cell.boundary.origin[2] 
        edgecasey2::Bool = cell.data.list[i].y == cell.boundary.origin[2] + cell.boundary.widths[2] 
        edgecasez1::Bool = cell.data.list[i].z == cell.boundary.origin[3] 
        edgecasez2::Bool = cell.data.list[i].z == cell.boundary.origin[3] + cell.boundary.widths[3] 
        
        edgecasex1 ? edgecorrectionx::Float64 += (cell.boundary.widths[1]+10)^(-1/cell.boundary.widths[1]) : nothing 
        edgecasex2 ? edgecorrectionx::Float64 += (cell.boundary.widths[1]+10)^(-1/cell.boundary.widths[1]) : nothing
        edgecasey1 ? edgecorrectiony::Float64 += (cell.boundary.widths[2]+10)^(-1/cell.boundary.widths[2]) : nothing
        edgecasey2 ? edgecorrectiony::Float64 += (cell.boundary.widths[2]+10)^(-1/cell.boundary.widths[2]) : nothing
        edgecasez1 ? edgecorrectionz::Float64 += (cell.boundary.widths[3]+10)^(-1/cell.boundary.widths[3]) : nothing
        edgecasez2 ? edgecorrectionz::Float64 += (cell.boundary.widths[3]+10)^(-1/cell.boundary.widths[3]) : nothing
      
        case1 = cell.boundary.origin[1] < cell.data.list[i].x + edgecorrectionx < cell.boundary.origin[1] + cell.boundary.widths[1]  
        case2 = cell.boundary.origin[2] < cell.data.list[i].y + edgecorrectiony < cell.boundary.origin[2] + cell.boundary.widths[2] 
        case3 = cell.boundary.origin[3] < cell.data.list[i].z + edgecorrectionz < cell.boundary.origin[3] + cell.boundary.widths[3] 
        if case1 && case2 && case3 == true 
            myindex += Int(1)
            cell.data.list[myindex] = cell.data.list[i] 
        end # end conditional
    end # End the for loop
    
    cell.data.endindex = myindex
    myindex == r.tolerance
end # End function

function refine_data(r::MyRefinery, cell::Cell, indices)
    cell.data 
end # End function

function intersects(cell, mydroplet)
        case1x = mydroplet.x - mydroplet.searchradius + 2 * mydroplet.searchradius <= cell.boundary.origin[1]
        case2x = mydroplet.x - mydroplet.searchradius >= cell.boundary.origin[1] + cell.boundary.widths[1] 
        casex = case1x || case2x
    
        case1y = mydroplet.y - mydroplet.searchradius + 2 * mydroplet.searchradius <= cell.boundary.origin[2]
        case2y = mydroplet.y - mydroplet.searchradius >= cell.boundary.origin[2] + cell.boundary.widths[2] 
        casey = case1y || case2y
        
        case1z = mydroplet.z - mydroplet.searchradius + 2 * mydroplet.searchradius <= cell.boundary.origin[3]
        case2z = mydroplet.z - mydroplet.searchradius >= cell.boundary.origin[3] + cell.boundary.widths[3] 
        casez = case1z || case2z
        
        !(casex || casey || casez)
  
end # End function

function contains(point, mydroplet)
xdist = mydroplet.x - point.x
ydist = mydroplet.y - point.y
zdist = mydroplet.z - point.z
sqrt(xdist^2 + ydist^2 + zdist^2) <= mydroplet.radius+point.radius && (sqrt(xdist^2 + ydist^2 + zdist^2) != 0)
end  # End function 

function query(cell, mydroplet, xyzaccel, flux, L, k, boolean_osm, D, jvec, accelerationvec) 
    if intersects(cell, mydroplet) == false
        return nothing
    else 
        if isleaf(cell)
            for i in 1 : length(cell.data.list) 
                contains(cell.data.list[i], mydroplet) ? xyzaccel .+= mygetaccelerationandflux(cell.data.list[i], mydroplet, L, k, boolean_osm, D, jvec, accelerationvec)[1]  : nothing
                contains(cell.data.list[i], mydroplet) ? flux .+= mygetaccelerationandflux(cell.data.list[i], mydroplet, L, k, boolean_osm, D, jvec, accelerationvec)[2]  : nothing
            end # End the for loop
        end # End the conditional

        if !isleaf(cell) 
            query(cell[1,1,1], mydroplet, xyzaccel, flux, L, k, boolean_osm, D, jvec, accelerationvec)
            query(cell[1,1,2], mydroplet, xyzaccel, flux, L, k, boolean_osm, D, jvec, accelerationvec)
            query(cell[1,2,1], mydroplet, xyzaccel, flux, L, k, boolean_osm, D, jvec, accelerationvec)
            query(cell[1,2,2], mydroplet, xyzaccel, flux, L, k, boolean_osm, D, jvec, accelerationvec)
            
            query(cell[2,2,2], mydroplet, xyzaccel, flux, L, k, boolean_osm, D, jvec, accelerationvec)
            query(cell[2,2,1], mydroplet, xyzaccel, flux, L, k, boolean_osm, D, jvec, accelerationvec)
            query(cell[2,1,2], mydroplet, xyzaccel, flux, L, k, boolean_osm, D, jvec, accelerationvec)
            query(cell[2,1,1], mydroplet, xyzaccel, flux, L, k, boolean_osm, D, jvec, accelerationvec)
        end # End conditional
        
    end # End conditional    
    # Perform the final calculations 

    return xyzaccel
    return flux
end # End function 

function mygetaccelerationandflux(fardrop::Droplet, neardrop::Droplet, L, k, boolean_osm, D, jvec, accelerationvec)#::Matrix{Float64}       
    xdist = fardrop.x - neardrop.x
    ydist = fardrop.y - neardrop.y 
    zdist = fardrop.z - neardrop.z
    directionx = xdist/sqrt(xdist^2 + ydist^2 + zdist^2)
    directiony = ydist/sqrt(xdist^2 + ydist^2 + zdist^2)
    directionz = zdist/sqrt(xdist^2 + ydist^2 + zdist^2)
    mybilayerdist = L * (neardrop.radius + fardrop.radius)
    
    accelerationvec[1] = directionx * -k * (abs(mybilayerdist * directionx) - abs(xdist))
    accelerationvec[2] = directiony * -k * (abs(mybilayerdist * directiony) - abs(ydist)) 
    accelerationvec[3] = directionz * -k * (abs(mybilayerdist * directionz) - abs(zdist))   

    # =================== The osmolarity part of the code ================================= # 
    intersectcase1 =  neardrop.radius + fardrop.radius - sqrt(xdist^2 + ydist^2 + zdist^2) >= 0
    intersectcase2 = sqrt(xdist^2 + ydist^2 + zdist^2) + neardrop.radius  - fardrop.radius >= 0
    intersectcase3 = sqrt(xdist^2 + ydist^2 + zdist^2) + fardrop.radius  - neardrop.radius >= 0

    # jvec = 0 
    if boolean_osm[1] >= 1.0 
        if (intersectcase1 && intersectcase2 && intersectcase3)
            component1 = (sqrt(xdist^2 + ydist^2 + zdist^2)^2 - fardrop.radius^2 + neardrop.radius^2)^2
            component2 = 4 * sqrt(xdist^2 + ydist^2 + zdist^2)^2 * neardrop.radius^2
            component3 = component2 - component1
            component4 = 1/(2*sqrt(xdist^2 + ydist^2 + zdist^2)) * sqrt(component3)
            mycircular_area = pi * component4^2
            osmdiff = neardrop.osmolarity - fardrop.osmolarity
            jvec = D * mycircular_area * osmdiff
        end # End the conditional
    end # End the conditional

    return accelerationvec, jvec
end # End function

end # End module 



module NateOdeManager
using ..NateDropOde
using ..DropletFields
using ..MyOvitoPrint
using DifferentialEquations
ICmatrix = [3 0.1 3 0 0 0 0 0; 3 1. 9 0 0 0 0 0; 3 0.4 14 0 0 0 0 0]
ρ = 0.2 # The density of the droplet, used to calculate the mass of each droplet within the system as a function of radius. To wit Eqn = mass(rho,volume(radius))
k = 1000. # The spring force between each droplet 
L = 0.8 # The natural length proportional to the radii that droplets will settle at
γ = 30. # The simplified version of both fluid response and spring damping in the system
timeend = 250. # The time at which the ODE will end
D = 2. *10^-2  # The rate at which diffusion will happen in the system
boolean_osm = [0.0] # The "on" switch for when the diffusion in the sytem will activate
tstepextract = Int(timeend * 10) 
ICvector = reshape(ICmatrix, :, 1);
dropletcount = size(ICmatrix,1)
tspan = (0.0, timeend);
dradii = zeros(dropletcount,1)
dosmolarities = zeros(dropletcount,1)
dvelocities = zeros(3*dropletcount,1)
accelerationvec = zeros(3,1)
xyzaccel = zeros(3,1)
flux = zeros(1,1)
    # Create the vector of droplets that will be fed into the main ODE 
    droplets = Droplet[] # Change this to a vector that needs to be imported in 
    for i in 1:dropletcount
        droplet = Droplet(0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.)  #< ----- > THE FORMATTING FOR THE DROPLET
        push!(droplets, droplet)
    end # End the for loop
p = [dropletcount, k, L, γ, D, boolean_osm, dradii, dosmolarities, dvelocities, ρ, accelerationvec, droplets, xyzaccel, flux] 
prob = ODEProblem(natedropode, ICvector, tspan, p)
sol = solve(prob, Tsit5(),saveat = 0.1, dt = 0.1)
myovitoprint(sol, dropletcount)
end # End module NateOdeManager
```

Comment: 1) It's unclear what the second half of your post is asking or how it is related to the memory issue. If it's not related, remove it and perhaps make a different post. 2) Please provide runnable code, in your first half `u` is not defined so it won't run. 3) You're doing some things that hurt performance e.g. global scope instead of methods, and the type annotations are not actually helping (please study the documentation). 4) You're right, it is really odd that the `searchradius` line is where you're seeing allocations, please provide details on your memory profiling method.

Comment: du and u are part of an ordinary differential equation. The initial conditions vector for the differential equation is given as an unraveled matrix that is used for the particle simulation, from another file. The specifics are given here: https://github.com/ntm529/natedrop . You can see a specific and runnable example of how the code works at the bottom of the readme. I am most interested in how I am using global scope instead of methods. Can you name which lines are causing that issue?I am using coverage.jl to analyze the code. You can see memory allocs here: https://imgur.com/a/o7ggbDP

Comment: 1) links to code are not encouraged on stackoverflow, write a MWE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 2) Global scope is just the level of a module or a script. Julia's compiler can't make assumptions about the types of global variables, so it can't optimize well. The compiler can try to infer types of variables inside *methods*, though, so code in methods often use less time and memory. 3) idk what memory profiler that is, but 422592+1267776=1690368, so maybe that's just an artifact of being the for-loop's last line. You could swap it with a previous line to check.

Comment: I agree with @BatWannaBe , please simplify the problem to its bare essentials and post the relevant code for that as a coherent whole. The code here is scattered, hard to follow, and mixes the useful with the extraneous. Define your `u`, `droplets`, `dropletcount`, and any other necessary variable, in a separate script file, replicate the issue there, and post that code as a whole. Also, please mention your Julia version too.

Comment: Did you check type stability? It's impossible to run your code so nobody can actually help you.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Julia. I posted the MWE example of the code as an edit at the bottom of my question. It should be fully runnable. I reduced it as much as I can, many of the memory allocations are evenly on lines 48-92 and are intimately tied to some of the other algorithms. The ODE has an initial condition vector which is (I think) the initial U vector. The du vector and it's implementation I do not know the specifics of, it seems to be the size of the Initial conditions vector and is handled by the ODE solver. The same memory allocation issues are persisting.